# pin UiTableView to (view controller)view with layout anchor

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios9, nslayoutanchor

I want to 'pin' a tableview to it's container, the view of a view controller. Since UIView does not have anchor properties, I try to do it with the layoutMarginsGuide.

> UIView does not provide anchor properties for the layout margin attributes. Instead, the layoutMarginsGuide property provides a UILayoutGuide object that represents these margins. Use the guide’s anchor properties to create your constraints.

```
        let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    self.tableView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor).active = true
    self.tableView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor).active = true
```

But running this code I get the following error:

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason:   'Unable to activate constraint with items <UITableView: 0x7fdfd0ab5e00; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fdfd8452e00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdfd84c11c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> and <UILayoutGuide: 0x7fdfd86d7ca0 - "UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, owningView = <UIView: 0x7fdfd75a8aa0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdfd0409270>>> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

The important part:

```
    ...because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

But how is this supposed to work?

Comment: No such issues on iOS 9 simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first change constraint to be like this 
       `self.tableView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
       self.tableView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor).active = true`

if the problem still exist ensure that tableview is added as a subview of view

```
view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I indeed had added the tableView _after_ assigning the constraints